# Typescript: Overriding parent class properties in child

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, overriding, es6-class

Given the following case:

```js
class Parent {
    propStr = "Hello";
    propNum = 42;

    constructor(propShared) {
        console.log(this.propStr); // Hello
        console.log(this.propNum); // 42
        console.log(propShared); // w/e
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    propStr = "Hi"; // overridden
    propNum = 1337; // overridden

    constructor(propShared) {
        super(propShared);
    }
}

let c = new Child("Foobar");
```

How do I make sure that the parent properties are properly overridden so that the console.log prints the child's properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned typescript, you can use a feature of typescript called [*Parameter Properties*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties):

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(public propStr = "Hello", public propNum = 42, public propShared: any) {
        console.log(this.propStr); // Hello
        console.log(this.propNum); // 42
        console.log(this.propShared); // w/e
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(propShared: any) {
        super("Hi", 1337, propShared);
    }
}

let c = new Child("Foobar");
```

The output will be exactly what you were expecting.

Answer (score 4):

You are logging the properties from within the parent constructor, where they are *not yet* overwritten by the child constructor code that runs after `super()`. You should only do initialisation within the constructor, not execute any side effects:

```
class Parent {
    propStr = "Hello";
    propNum = 42;

    log() {
        console.log(this.propStr);
        console.log(this.propNum);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    propStr = "Hi"; // overridden
    propNum = 1337; // overridden
}

const c = new Child("Foobar");
c.log()
```

If you want the initialisation to depend on things chosen elsewhere, including child classes, make them parameters. You can still give them reasonable defaults:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(propStr = "Hello", propNum = 42, propShared) {
        this.propStr = propStr;
        this.propNum = propNum;
        this.propShared = propShared;
    }
    log() {
        console.log(this.propStr);
        console.log(this.propNum);
        console.log(this.propShared);
    }   
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(propShared) {
        super("Hi", 1337, propShared);
    }
}

const c = new Child("Foobar");
c.log();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use getter. Then parent constructor see value declared in child.

```
class Parent {
    get propStr: string {
      return "Hello"
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    get propStr: string {
      return "Hi"
    }
}
```